# Download .msg file from jQuery in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, outlook, msg

My goal is to make an archive of a .msg file. I know how to let users upload them but I don't know how to let them download in IE/Edge. I need to do this in javascript/jQuery

In Chrome it works. It launches the suggestion to simply open or download

```
location.href = 'domain/path/filename.msg';
```

In IE/Edge it is not working. I tried the same thing and few others but it opens a new tab with random characters in it. If someone knows how to do it on IE/Edge can you let me know.

Comment: use the ´download.js´ script https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs

Comment: can you explain a bit ? I don't know how to use it. The only thing that i have is the link of the file.

Comment: Well.. download the library, include it `<script src="download.js"></script>` and use it when you need like this `download(your-file-url)`